# Django ) AttributeError : 'datetime.date' object when trying to get an object of model

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models

I need to update a model object and save so that this result can be reflected.

But when I try to get an object of this model **that I checked already this object exists**,

```
modelOne = lkmModel.objects.get(id=1)
```

I got an error :

> AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'

I searched already , yes I have a field about 'date' but this is field is :

```
matchingDate = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.date.today())
```

As I searched, my field 'matchingDate' is not a problem, isn't it?

I'm going to write my models.py below :

```
from django.db import models
import datetime

class lkmModel(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField()
    matchingDate = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.date.today())
    isNoon = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    dayOfWeek = models.IntegerField()
    profileUrl = models.TextField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20,default=None)
    affiliation = models.CharField(max_length=20,default=None)
    age = models.IntegerField(db_index=True)
    residence = models.CharField(max_length=20,default=None)
    bloodType = models.CharField(max_length=20,default=None)
    religion = models.CharField(max_length=20,default=None)

    personality = models.TextField(default=None)
    appearance = models.TextField(default=None)
    hobby = models.TextField(default=None)
    ability = models.TextField(default=None)
    idealType = models.TextField(default=None)
    career = models.TextField(default=None)
    best = models.TextField(default=None)

    badge1 = models.CharField(max_length=10,default=None)
    badge2 = models.CharField(max_length=10,default=None)
    badge3 = models.CharField(max_length=10,default=None)

    manual = models.TextField(default=None)
    point = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return  self.name
```

Even though I changed 'matchingDate' field to :

```
matchingDate = models.DateTimeField()
```

When I queried , exactly the same error is occurring,
***I think it is more serious than I expected...***

UPDATE!
It's the image of the screen after querying 'matchingDate' columnn
[image]

Is there anything I did wrong?
My python version is 3.4.4 and django's version is 1.9.2

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your model cannot have a field named `id` without it being declared as a `primary_key`. Secondly, while creating django models use `django.utils.timezone.now` instead of `datetime`.

The root cause of the problem you have is that you're giving `datetime.date` object as default to a `datetime.datetime` instance. Hence it says that `tzinfo` attribute i.e. time zone information is missing. `tzinfo` is an attribute to `datetime` and `time` objects, not `date` objects. You can read more about it here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

So, after modifications your `models.py` should look like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class lkmModel(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    matchingDate = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    isNoon = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    dayOfWeek = models.IntegerField()
    profileUrl = models.TextField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20,default=None)
    affiliation = models.CharField(max_length=20,default=None)
    age = models.IntegerField(db_index=True)
    residence = models.CharField(max_length=20,default=None)
    bloodType = models.CharField(max_length=20,default=None)
    religion = models.CharField(max_length=20,default=None)

    personality = models.TextField(default=None)
    appearance = models.TextField(default=None)
    hobby = models.TextField(default=None)
    ability = models.TextField(default=None)
    idealType = models.TextField(default=None)
    career = models.TextField(default=None)
    best = models.TextField(default=None)

    badge1 = models.CharField(max_length=10,default=None)
    badge2 = models.CharField(max_length=10,default=None)
    badge3 = models.CharField(max_length=10,default=None)

    manual = models.TextField(default=None)
    point = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return  self.name
```

This should solve the problem.

Comment: OK, then can you explain why these points you pointed affected the error 'Attribute error : datetime.date' doesn't have a field tzinfo'?

Comment: @LKM I've edited my answer to include the root cause of your problem. Please take a look.

Comment: But it returns the same error after changing just what you said. anyway thank you for fighting for me

Comment: Did you migrated the changes and then re-instantiated the database?

If you're trying to get that old object it would lead to an error.

Comment: I did 'python manage.py makemigrations' and then 'python manage.py migrate' and I did test and I failed, is there something I'm missing now?

Comment: Can you delete the previous database and create a fresh one? Basically delete all objects of this model and then create new object and try to get it.

Comment: Wow, you teach me a lot! But if I delete the previous database, my table and records are deleted too, isn't it? How to manage this situation?

Comment: Basically you need to delete the records corresponding to this table. Then create new object and test it. It would work. I wonder that the previous record you have in db is still date instance and hence the error

Comment: Hmm.. I updated the post for showing the screen after quering 'matchingDate' column. As you see it does work, I save 'matchingDate' data by 'todayDate = datetime.date.today()'

Comment: Dude, that is exactly what I'm trying to tell you! Your `matching_date` column has `date` object not `datetime` objects and thus, you're getting `tzinfo attribute error`. You need to change all these entries to `datetime` instances and then it would work from django. I've tested my implementation and it works perfectly.

Comment: I'm really in being confused. I just need the information of year , month and day. So I think I have to change matchingDate as DateField not DateTimeField, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, if you just want date, then it should be `DateField`.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing is do not use id in models. Django adds that automatically as the primary key.

The other thing is that you are trying to fill date object in a Datetime field. Datetime is different from Date.

```
matchingDate = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.date.today())
```

Instead use

```
matchingDate = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
```

Better still, use auto_now_add if you want to use the default time as the time of creation of the object.(Sorry if i am misunderstanding the purpose)

```
matchingDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

But the actual error comes from timezone info thing.

Install pytz (`pip install pytz`)

and try to use the datetime with time zone info (tzinfo) instead of a naive one.

```
time = datetime.now(pytz.utc)
```

This gives timezone enabled datetime

datetime.date has no attribute tzinfo. You have to use it on datetime object only.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work as what you said. thank you anyway!